# Does Android Manifest xml file has anything to do with the fact that Unity game isn't working on some android phones?

Tags: android, xml, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, manifest

I am not an android developer, but a beginner Unity game dev. I'm trying to make a game for android where access to the camera roll/gallery is required. it has worked on the Huawei android version 9 so far.
I was wondering if it has something to do with the **android manifest**.

I used this free plug in to get the feature:https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/camera/android-photo-cropper-212385#description

This is the content of that file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
package="com.package.photocropper" android:versionName="1.0" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application>
    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale" android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActisvity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.photocropper.code.WebViewActivity" >
    </activity>
  </application>

  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />


</manifest>
```

The apk file crashes after opening the gallery and selecting the image.

I tried removing all tags except:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

but it did nothing.

Comment: Does the machines that crashes has External Storage?  Read following : https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: @jdweng no, but the one that worked doesn’t have it either

Comment: does that mean that when it’s importing the image it’s looking for somewhere to store that image temporarily but can’t access the necessary memory?

Comment: I assume the one that worked had the XML line, but didn't have External Storage.  What do you mean by "But It did Nothing".  Did app run?  Did it still crash?  You machine may not be able to open all types of images.  It could be the extension or it could be the size.  Every Image has an ASCII header that you can read with a text editor like notepad.  Not all machines are configured to read every type of image.  You may have a old driver that needs updating. Or the resolution of image may require more memory than your machine has.  When a machine doesn't have enough memory swap space in used.

Comment: i mean it would still open the app, allow opening of the gallery, selecting image and when it’s about to import the image it crashes, on some devices it would exit, on others it restarted. @jdweng do you know there’s a way to approach the manifest so that it works universally on all devices? maybe i have some extra code there that’s not needed

Comment: I don't have enough info.  The issue is not the xml file.  It is the code.  You need to find out where in code it is crashing.  Then modify to work with all machines.  You may have to limit file size or type of image.